# Decouple Azure WebRole from Web Application project

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I have an existing application hosted in Azure PAAS (Cloud Service).
I would like to decouple the Azure WebRole from my web application in order to allow an on-premise version of my application.
The main problem is that I inherit from the RoleEntryPoint in my web application and I don't see a way to have the Azure package add a dependency to my web role outside my web application.

Amir